# Similarity between clusters/groups?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, similarities, distance-functions

I have a dataset consisting of multiple groups in a high dimensional space. An example is shown below:

[image]

What would be the best way to calculate similarities between groups. Say how similar is group A to group B, group B to group C, etc?

I want to express this as I am working on a classification problem. If say, my model predicts instances that are belonging to group A, as group B often. It would be relevant to assess how similar group A is to group B.

One thing I have tried is calculating the centroids of each cluster and calculating euclidean distances between each cluster. But I am not sure if this is the best way to express similarties between the groups.

Comment: Excellent question

Comment: if the variables in the table are features of each row-wise observation, then you can use the group labels in the last column for your target /response variable in a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) if the observations within each group A, B, C can be assumed to be normally distributed. The GMM will learn the mean and covariance of each group, and can be represented as a chart displaying a cluster for each group